# Running tests with coverage using django-jenkins

Tags: django, jenkins, python-coverage, django-jenkins

I've got a couple of Django projects that I work on, and I use Jenkins for continuous integration purposes. I've had that arrangement up and running for a while and it works well.

I'd like to be able to generate automated test coverage reports and have Jenkins handle them as well. It looked to me like [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins) was the way to go for that, so I installed it and `coverage`.

Here's the relevant sections of my `settings.py`:

```
# Jenkins integration
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_jenkins',)
JENKINS_TASKS = ( 
    'django_jenkins.tasks.with_coverage',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_pylint',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.django_tests',
)
PROJECT_APPS = ['myapp']
```

Now, I can run `python manage.py jtest`, and it works as expected. However, if I run `python manage.py jenkins`, it errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/blah/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/blah/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/blah/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/blah/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 76, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/blah/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jenkins/management/commands/__init__.py", line 61, in __init__
    for module_name in self.get_task_list()]
  File "/home/matthew/Projects/blah/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_tests
```

I'm using the standard Django `TestCase` and `LiveServerTestCase` classes as the basis of my tests. Any idea where I'm going wrong here? The documentation seems to imply `django_tests` has been removed, but I can't find any indication as to how you run the Django tests now.

I'm using Django 1.6.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just realised I've been a bit of a numpty. All I needed to do was drop the `django_tests` line, like this:

```
# Jenkins integration
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_jenkins',)
JENKINS_TASKS = ( 
    'django_jenkins.tasks.with_coverage',
    'django_jenkins.tasks.run_pylint',
)
PROJECT_APPS = ['myapp']
```

And `django-jenkins` will run the tests without having to explicitly request that it does so.

Answer (score 5):

There is a change in the latest version of django_jenkins (0.18.0) so that the ***django_jenkins.tasks.with_coverage*** Jenkins Task is also no longer needed.

Instead, you execute the test run as follows:

```
python manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage
```

or

```
python3 manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage
```

You can find out more on the project's [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins/issues/311).